# Weird line breaks in a styled unordered list?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, html-lists

I'm having a very strange specific problem and I'm going to try to paste the code in here without confusing the issue too much.  I've got an unordered list that uses a stylesheet to put each list item into a little square... but after a certain point, the line breaks kind of go nuts.  If you add or take away different ones, the line breaks move around and I can't for the life of me figure out what's happening.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="primaryStyle.css" />
</head>

<body>
<center> 

    <table class="table" border="0" width="750"> 
    <tr>
        <td>
        <div id="productresults">


                    <ul class="productlist" >
                                            <li class="productresultli"><center>
                        <span id="Span3">Seasonal Fruit Tray</span><br />
                        <span id="Span4">$9.00</span><br /></center>
                    </li>
                    <li class="productresultli"><center>
                        <span id="Span5">Seasonal Fruit Tray</span><br />
                        <span id="Span6">$9.00</span><br /></center>
                    </li>

                    <li class="productresultli"><center>
                        <span id="Span17">Seasonal Fruit Tray</span><br />
                        <span id="Span18">$9.00</span><br /></center>
                    </li>

                    <li class="productresultli"><center>
                        <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lvProducts_NameLabel_12">Mayonaise</span><br />
                        <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lvProducts_PriceLabel_12">$5.00</span><br /></center>
                    </li>

                    <li class="productresultli"><center>
                        <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lvProducts_NameLabel_13">Ketchup</span><br />
                        <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lvProducts_PriceLabel_13">$3.50</span><br /></center>
                    </li>

                    <li class="productresultli"><center>
                        <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lvProducts_NameLabel_14">Raspberry Chiptole Sauce</span><br />
                        <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lvProducts_PriceLabel_14">$10.00</span><br /></center>
                    </li>


                    <li class="productresultli"><center>
                        <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lvProducts_NameLabel_14">Raspberry Chiptole Sauce</span><br />
                        <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lvProducts_PriceLabel_14">$10.00</span><br /></center>
                    </li>

                    <li class="productresultli"><center>
                        <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lvProducts_NameLabel_14">Raspberry Chiptole Sauce</span><br />
                        <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lvProducts_PriceLabel_14">$10.00</span><br /></center>
                    </li>

                    <li class="productresultli"><center>
                        <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lvProducts_NameLabel_14">Raspberry Chiptole Sauce</span><br />
                        <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lvProducts_PriceLabel_14">$10.00</span><br /></center>
                    </li>

                    <li class="productresultli"><center>
                        <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lvProducts_NameLabel_14">Raspberry Chiptole Sauce</span><br />
                        <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lvProducts_PriceLabel_14">$10.00</span><br /></center>
                    </li>
                    <li class="productresultli"><center>
                        <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lvProducts_NameLabel_13">Ketchup</span><br />
                        <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lvProducts_PriceLabel_13">$3.50</span><br /></center>
                    </li>
                    <li class="productresultli"><center>
                        <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lvProducts_NameLabel_13">Ketchup</span><br />
                        <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lvProducts_PriceLabel_13">$3.50</span><br /></center>
                    </li>

                    <li class="productresultli"><center>
                        <span id="Span17">Seasonal Fruit Tray</span><br />
                        <span id="Span18">$9.00</span><br /></center>
                    </li>

                    <li class="productresultli"><center>
                        <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lvProducts_NameLabel_12">Mayonaise</span><br />
                        <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lvProducts_PriceLabel_12">$5.00</span><br /></center>
                    </li>

                    <li class="productresultli"><center>
                        <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lvProducts_NameLabel_13">Ketchup</span><br />
                        <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lvProducts_PriceLabel_13">$3.50</span><br /></center>
                    </li>

                    <li class="productresultli"><center>
                        <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lvProducts_NameLabel_14">Raspberry Chiptole Sauce</span><br />
                        <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_lvProducts_PriceLabel_14">$10.00</span><br /></center>
                    </li>

                </ul>


        </div></td></tr>
    </table>
 </center>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the stylesheet I'm using (primaryStyle.css)

```
body 
{
margin: 20px 0;     
padding: 0;
font: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #000;
background-attachment: fixed;
text-align: center;
height: 100%;
background: #ABCDEF;
}


.productresultli
{
display: inline;
float: left;
margin-right: 15px;
margin-bottom: 15px;
width: 113px;
padding: 5px;
text-align: center;
}

.productlist
{
float: left;
}
```

Does anyone have ANY idea why this is happening?  Any help would be appreciated.  If I'm not quite making sense, please let me know.  THANKS!

Comment: Would’ve been easier for everyone to identify your problem, if you posted a link to a demo page or at least a screenshot depicting the issue.

Comment: A jsfiddle would be helpful. Also the `<center>` tag is deprecated and you should get rid of those ugly `<br/>` tags inside your list and use padding and/or margin instead. Why are you using a table anyway? It makes no sense there...

Comment: `float:left` causes `display:inline` to be ignored, since it's meaningless for a floating element.  Also you haven't specified which browser, and whether other browsers have the same problem.

Comment: Sorry, this is generated code from .NET.  I tried to clean it up by stripping out most of it, but some of it made it through.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The varying heights of the `li` elements are causing the elements to be placed unevenly. For eg, if you define a fixed height of say `height:200px`, you'll notice that the `li's` align properly. Since the heights of the individual `li's` are different and each `li` has a `margin-bottom`, the list items are being arranged based on the space available. Set a fixed height and the `li's` will align properly.

I've created a fiddle for you to well, fiddle with - http://jsfiddle.net/2YSdT/1/

Comment: Awesome, the fiddle's neat, haven't used that before.  I'll try this out as soon as I get home

Answer (score 0):

After looking through the code you have posted I think what you are describing is being caused by not clearing your floats. To fix this add the class last to the final list item on each line. Then use the pseudo class :after to clear them such as the following.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
   <li>Item</li>
   <li>Item2</li>
   <li class="last">Item3</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
li:after {
  clear:both;
}
```